# How to mix const and let when using object or array destructuring assignment in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Example :

```
const foo = {a: "A", b: "B"}
const {a, b} = foo
```

What if I want `b` to be a variable using `let` ?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It seems like you can't differentiate variable's declaration in a one line. However, you could split it into two lines and use a different variable declaration, depends on which variable you want to get.

```
const { a } = foo; 
let { b } = foo;
```

Comment: if I want to de-structure a function call, I need 3 lines to do it and to come up with an intermediary variable name

Comment: The sucky scenario that this answer doesn't call out in the code example is `...rest`.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to use array destructuring assignment with const and let you can use elision. Let's consider an example:

```
const [a, b, c] = foo;
```

If you want to 'a' be a let, and 'b' and 'c' const, you can write:

```
let [ a ] = foo;
const [, b, c] = foo;
```

Another way is to use the fact that array is an object. So you can write it also like this:

```
let [a] = foo;
const {1: b, 2: c} = foo;
```

All about destructing can be find here: [http://exploringjs.com](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)